# big ints with boost : too large to be represented in any integer type

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I think i don't get something.

Is the class `cpp_int` from `boost::multiprecision` supposed to hold integers as big as one want ?
Let's say i want to store the following ridiculously big integer. How am I supposed to do it ?

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

cpp_int n = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
```

The following code returns

`error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type`

Comment: C++ itself only supports integer literals of a certain size.  Most likely that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: `99999999999...999` before it gets assigned to the mp::cpp_int is an integer and has already overflowed.

Comment: `cpp_int` has a constructor that takes a string as its argument, although I'm trying to find a documentation page with more information than just [this one](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html). ETA: [This page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html) gives some examples of using string ctors.

Comment: Note that in practice it is unlikely that you will have to initialize an object with such a giant magic number.

Comment: try `cpp_int n("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");`

Comment: Thanks, it was actually one of my troubles, finding other documentation for boost libs, better than the only one i found and the one you linked to.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying some arithmetics to play around some RSA keys. Your solution worked also with hex numbers. This magic number is not meant to be exaclty this one.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks actually it was in the errow thrown : `integer litteral is too large`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper -- Most, if not all big number libraries must have a string constructor or similar.  The C++ standard integer types just cannot represent so many digits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting constant too big error while using boost library (cpp\_int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840403/getting-constant-too-big-error-while-using-boost-library-cpp-int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As detailed in the documentation, you need to construct with a string:

```
cpp_int n{"999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"};
```

See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html