# boost::multiprecision::cpp_int acting like unsigned long long

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multiprecision

So I have a programming assignment in which I have to work with 64 digit numbers. I am currently using the boost::multiprecision::cpp_int library but I'm not able to use it on large numbers.

For example-

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int n1 =123341257612045876129038576124390847381295732;   
}
```

This is giving the error that the code is too long.
After experimentation, it seems like cpp_int (supposed to contain as large a number as you want) is acting like an unsigned long long (shown in the picture above), how do I solve this?

Comment: 2^64 = 1E19... your n1 there is much larger than that. Is multiprecision lib supposed to be able to do arbitrary precision arithmetic?

Comment: @MFerguson It's supposed to contain as large a number as you give it so this should work. I've also tried using int1024_t which has 1024 bits which should contain this number. But all of these are being interpreted as unsigned long longs.

Comment: `123341257612045876129038576124390847381295732` is a numeric literal in C++ which cannot exceed `uintmax_t` range so obviously you can't use it for bigints if they're bigger than `uintmax_t`. You need to let `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` parse the number from string

Comment: duplicates: [big ints with boost : too large to be represented in any integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64793676/995714), [Getting constant too big error while using boost library (cpp_int)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61840403/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the string constructor, because you cannot express the initializer in C++, otherwise.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b521efd24f354b9)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int n1("123341257612045876129038576124390847381295732");
    n1 *= n1;
    n1 *= n1;

    std::cout << n1 << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
231437371927256216552064578371685752056581253909626001052591740261122589692668963795268703088073326299461305156397520102373182511147316463882992573577585984095769469664077598976
```

Which is ~2.31 × 10^176